# Issue with home network connection

Tags: home-networking

I have the following network topology at home: [image: Home topology]
Lately I've been having issues with the switch, the link from the main router to the switch just dies, no blinking light either on the router or on the switch for that link. The connection to the TV and the other router is still up, everything ok there.

To fix that what worked for me the last couple of times was:

- unplug the network cable connecting the switch to the wall socket
- connect my laptop with it's own network cable directly to the wall socket (it connects successfully)
- reconnect the network cable from the switch to the wall socket (now light on the switch and router starts blinking and network works on both PC and Laptop connected to switch)

As a note, the main router is in one room, the switch is another room, the TV's in separate rooms also so there is some distance and the network cables are under the floor, so no easy access to them.

Do you have any idea what the issue might be and how should I go about investigating it?

Comment: Have you ruled out the switch being dodgy ?  Sounds like you could temporarily throw any switch in there and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: I think it's not the switch because initially the 2nd router was where the switch is now and I was getting the issues. Also the switch is brand new, this is the model https://www.tp-link.com/us/products/details/cat-5582_TL-SG1008D.html